# Predicates and quantifiers

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

*Let $L(x,y)$ be the statement "x lives with y", where the domain for both x and y is all people.*

How would I describe the below using the above statement?

*Nobody lives with y* becomes $¬∃xL(x,y)$ if my understanding is correct, but what if the question is *nobody lives with John*, how do I parse this? $¬∃xL(x,John)$?

I'm just not sure how to 'inject' quantifiers into logic.

Comment: 'Nobody lives with $y$' looks dodgy. Here $y$ is unquantified. Are you supposed to treat is as a variable?

Comment: @GitGud: it was purely an example. I know how silly it looks, but it was just a means for myself to illustrate my problem in writing these out.

Comment: Oh, I see. In that case you should use a letter like $a$ instead of $y$, because $x,y,z,\ldots$ are supposed to be variables while $a,b,c,\ldots$ are supposed to be constants. This is just a convention though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's exactly the same idea as "nobody lives with $y$," in the specific case $y=\text{John}$. It's fine.

Comment: So $¬∃xL(x,John)$ would be correct, then?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Absolutely right.

Comment: Would either of you have a resource you would suggest for further reading? Something seems iffy about all of this, like I am missing something. Take for example _Everybody lives with somebody_, I interpret this as $∀x∃yL(x,y)$ but again, I'm not sure if my formatting is correct.

Comment: @riista You can try [Language, Proof and Logic](http://ssdi.di.fct.unl.pt/~pb/cadeiras/lc/0102/lpl%20textbook.pdf).

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a go. I should clarify that the concept of quantifiers I understand fully, just not the conventions in writing them out.

Comment: Your formulation is again perfect (I've no resources to offer, sadly). The verbal translation of your quantified statement is: "For every person, there is someone who lives with them." This says precisely that "Everybody lives with somebody," since $L(x,y)$ if and only if $L(y,x)$.